# How to get elapsed time of expo video?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, expo

Im using the Expo-Video-Player package, and went to get the elapsed time of when a video is played.

```
<ExpoVideoPlayer
    videoProps={{
    resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_STRETCH,
    source: {
        uri: videoUrl,
        },
    }}
    inFullscreen={false}
    showControlsOnLoad={true}
    videoBackground={"#fff"}
    height={200}
    videoRef={video}
    showFullscreenButton={false}
    playIcon={() => playIcon}
    replayIcon={() => replayIcon}
    pauseIcon={() => pauseIcon}
    sliderColor={"#CE4A52"}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, call this in the props.

```
playbackCallBack={(e) => {
    console.log(e.positionMillis)
}
```

You can then adjust how often you want the event to fire (in ms) in the videoProps prop with progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 1000.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onPlaybackStatusUpdate` props. This is the callback function that receives a `PlaybackStatus` object as an argument.

`PlaybackStatus` object has `positionMillis` property, which is the current position of the playback head in milliseconds.

For example:

```
<Video
  { ...props }
  onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => console.log(status.positionMillis)}
/>
```

To learn more, see [Expo AV documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/av/), [Expo AV usage](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/#usage), [`positionMillis` property](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/video/#positionmillis)

Comment: I've tried this, and it still doesn't work - keep in mind im using the ExpoVideoPlayer. Here is my code:
`<ExpoVideoPlayer
videoProps={{
resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_STRETCH,
source: {
 uri: videoUrl,
 },
progressUpdateIntervalMillis: 100,
onPlaybackStatusUpdate: (status) => {
console.log(status.positionMillis);
},
}}`

Comment: please see https://snack.expo.dev/@pluto0104/video?platform=android